# search all the elements of array of strings in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to search all elements of an array of strings of the database and to return how many values are matched to the existing database entries..

database name = words , table name=collection , word is the coloumn in which array to bi searched

```
<?php
$array=array('abc','xyz','lmn','pqr');
@ $db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','words');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error:Could not connect to the database';
} else echo 'connected';

$db->select_db('words');

foreach($array as $s) {
    $query="select * from collection where word = '%".$s."%'";
    $result=$db->query($query);
}

if($result) echo $db->affected_rows;
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: it should be where word LIKE '%".addslashes($s)."%'"

Comment: A SELECT query doesn't update the affected rows counter.

Comment: @Andrew `addslashes()` is not meant for SQL escaping.

Comment: Btw, if the array is not too big you can generate a single query that will give you the answer in one shot, i.e. `WHERE word LIKE ? OR word LIKE ? OR ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = 0;
foreach($array as $s) {
    $query="select count(*) as number_match from collection where word = '%".$s."%'";
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($db->query($query));
    $result+= $row['number_match'];
}
```

Edit:
Yet better :

```
$words = implode("%','%",$array);
$query="select count(*) as number_match from collection where word in ('%$words%')";
var_dump(mysql_fetch_row($db->query($query));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
its not feasible to run query in for loop so, you can try below solution,

$array=array('abc','xyz','lmn','pqr');     
$query="select word from collection where word LIKE '%".$s."%'";
$result=$db->query($query);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
 {
   $tblarray[] =  $row['word'];
 }
foreach($tblarray as $k => $v)
{
 foreach($array AS $key => $value)
 {
   if (strpos($v, $value) !== false)
   {
    $finalarray[] = $v; 
   }
 }
}
```